# bootstrap alert-dismissable not working in django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

here is my html code

```
<div class="msg">
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
      ×
      </button>
      <strong>{{message}}</strong>
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

message is showing after form submission, but x button not working of collapse, how to resolve it, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If the default way pointed out in bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing) does not work for you, you can try to add an `id` to your button and use `javascript` to close it . Im using `jQuery` in my example. Also check that you have not missed out on any `cdn` required.

```js
$( "#alerto" ).click(function() {
  $( ".alert" ).alert('close');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="msg">
  {% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
    <button type="button" class="close" id="alerto" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>
  {% endfor %} {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with bootstrap in my Django template messages. Mine was solved by adding these scripts to my templates:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHaiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You might also want to add this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/pulse/bootstrap.min.css">
```